# Toggle button within popup binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I made an `UserControl` that contains three toggle buttons that are each bound to different items of the same `ObservableCollection`. The `UserControl` is later used inside a `Popup`.

For some reason, when I toggle one of them, on an other instance of the `UserControl` within an other popup, it is also toggled.

The three `ToggleButton`s inside the `UserControl` look like this :

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" LastChildFill="False" Margin="0, 0, 0, 8">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="left" Margin="0" Text="ROTATION" Foreground="{StaticResource BaseText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="25" Width="25" Tag="3" IsChecked="{Binding RotationAxis[2], ElementName=RotationPanel,  Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Click="ToggleButton_Click"  Content="Z"/>
    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding RotationAxis[1], ElementName=RotationPanel,  Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding RotationAxis[0], ElementName=RotationPanel,  Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

They are bound to this `DependencyProperty` :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RotationAxisProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("RotationAxis", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(RotationSelector), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string> { "True", "True", "True" }));
[Bindable(true)]
public ObservableCollection<string> RotationAxis
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)this.GetValue(RotationAxisProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(RotationAxisProperty, value); }
}
```

The `UserControl` is then used twice in my app :

```
<Popup x:Name="SpritePopupRotation">
    <CMiX:RotationSelector x:Name="SpriteSelectedRotation" RotationAxis="{Binding Datacontext.SpriteRotationAxis, ElementName=Ch_Parameters, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" AxisChanged="RotationSelector_AxisChanged"/>
</Popup>

<Popup x:Name="MaskPopupRotation">
    <CMiX:RotationSelector x:Name="MaskSelectedRotation" RotationAxis="{Binding Datacontext.MaskRotationAxis, ElementName=Ch_Parameters, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" AxisChanged="RotationSelector_AxisChanged"/>
</Popup>
```

Now, when I start my app, the three `ToggleButton`s from one `UserControl` look like they are bound to the other three of the other instance of the `UserControl`.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve]. There are a lot of unneeded things in your example that make it hard to read. Furthermore, `Datacontext` is not `DataContext`, and we don't see your view-models.

Comment: sure but what is the unneeded things you're talking about ? and in what "complete" way this shoud be ?

Comment: We don't need in the XAML markup the widths, heights, styles, tags, event handlers, not relevant bindings etc. They are not important for your issue but just bloat the whole markup with unneeded info.

Comment: I see, sorry about that, I removed all unnecessary XAML. You were right about the Datacontext / DataContext, I didn't see and no error anywhere. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Problem was : I wrote Datacontext, while it should have been "DataContext". But I didn't notice since I'm working for quite a while and no errors were thrown.

Comment: Stupid question I know: Did you make sure that MaskRotationAxis and SpriteSelectedRotation are not the identical object?

Comment: You **should not** provide default value for dependency properties that hold collections. The provided value is not created for each control separately, but is a single static instance shared by all the controls (hence your results). If you want the initial value to no be `null` set it in the control's constructor. See [Collection-Type DependencyProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/collection-type-dependency-properties).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple user controls share collection dependency property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214839/multiple-user-controls-share-collection-dependency-property)